# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__AddEventSource

Tags: c++, dllimport, dllexport

I have an application that seems on the surface to be straightforward, and is similar to scores of similar situations that have given me little or no trouble. After adapting a sample that I found on The Code Project, I set about to move the top level routine into a new console application, leaving the rest of the code to go into a conventional Win32 DLL. This is something that I've done dozens of times, and I know my way around `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` fairly well. I defined the usual pair of macros and preprocessor variables to tell the compiler to emit `__declspec(dllimport)` for the caller and `__declspec(dllexport)` for the callee. Every bit of this is "garden variety" Windows programming, yet the console program won't link.

Searching for answers, I used the `/EP` switch on the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to obtain copies of the preprocessor output of both affected programs.

The main routine, `ProcessTestCase_ELS`, is defined in a separate source file, `ProcessTestCase_ELS.cpp`. As you can imagine, the listing is rather lengthy, even with `WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN` defined, but the relevant bit is only the following handful of lines.

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the EVENTLOGGINGFORALL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. this symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// EVENTLOGGINGFORALL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, wheras this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.

//  ============================================================================
//  Install an app as a source of events under the name pszName into the Windows
//  Registry.
//  ============================================================================

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) DWORD AddEventSource
(
    PCTSTR pszName ,                // Pointer to string containing event source ID 
    PCTSTR pszMessages ,            // Optional (default = NULL)    pointer to string containing name of associated message file
    PCTSTR pszLogName ,             // Optional (default = NULL)    pointer to string containing name of event log
    PCTSTR pszCategories ,          // Optional (default = NULL)    pointer to string containing name of category message file
    DWORD  dwCategoryCount          // Optional (default = 0)       category count
) ;
```

The preprocessor output of the routine exported by the DLL is equally long, but the definition of the routine at issue is blessedly short. The entire routine follows.

```
//  ============================================================================
//  Install an app as a source of events under the name pszName into the Windows
//  Registry.
//  ============================================================================

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD AddEventSource
(
    PCTSTR pszName ,                // Pointer to string containing event source ID
    PCTSTR pszMessages ,            // Optional (default = NULL)    pointer to string containing name of associated message file
    PCTSTR pszLogName ,             // Optional (default = NULL)    pointer to string containing name of event log
    PCTSTR pszCategories ,          // Optional (default = NULL)    pointer to string containing name of category message file
    DWORD  dwCategoryCount          // Optional (default = 0)       category count
```

)
    {
        TCHAR   szPath [ 260 ] ;

```
    TCHAR * lpszPath        = ( TCHAR * ) &szPath ;
    HKEY    hRegKey         = 0 ;
    DWORD   dwError         = 0L ;

    sprintf ( szPath ,                                                                      // Output buffer
              "%s\\%s\\%s" ,                                                                // Format string
              "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\EventLog" ,                             // Substitute for token 1
              pszLogName
                  ? pszLogName
                  : "Application" ,                                                         // Substitute for token 2
              pszName ) ;                                                                   // Substitute for token 3

    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the event source registry key.
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    dwError                 = RegCreateKeyA ( (( HKEY ) (ULONG_PTR)((LONG)0x80000002) ) ,   // Hive Name
                                              szPath ,                                      // Key Name
                                              &hRegKey ) ;                                  // Pointer to place to store handle to key

    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  If pszMessages is NULL, assume that this module contains the messages,
    //  and get its absolute (fully qualfied) name.
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if ( !(pszMessages) )
    {
        if ( !(( HMODULE ) GetModuleFileNameA ( m_hinstDLL , szPath , 260 )) )              // Sze of buffer, in TCHARs.
        {
            return util::ReportErrorOnConsole ( ) ;
        }   // Unless ( ( HMODULE ) GetModuleFileName ( m_hinstDLL , szPath , MAX_PATH ) )
    }   // Unless ( pszMessages )

    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Register EventMessageFile.
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    dwError                 = RegSetValueExA ( hRegKey ,                                    // Handle to key
                                               "EventMessageFile" ,                         // Value Name
                                               0x00000000L ,                                // Reserved - pass NULL
                                               ( 2 ) ,                                      // Value type
                                               ( PBYTE ) szPath ,                           // Value data
                                                ( ( ( strlen ( ( LPCTSTR ) szPath ) + 1 ) * sizeof ( TCHAR ) ) ) ) ;    // Size of value data - Macro TCharBufSizeP6C encapsulates all of this: ( _tcslen ( szPath ) + 1 ) * sizeof TCHAR )

    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Register supported event types.
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DWORD dwTypes           = 0x0001
                              | 0x0002
                              | 0x0004 ;

    dwError                 = RegSetValueExA ( hRegKey ,                                    // Handle to key
                                               "TypesSupported" ,                           // Value Name
                                               0x00000000L ,                                // Reserved - pass NULL
                                               ( 4 ) ,                                      // Value type
                                               ( LPBYTE ) &dwTypes ,                        // Value data
                                               sizeof dwTypes ) ;                           // Size of value data

    if ( dwError )
    {
        return util::ReportErrorOnConsole ( dwError ) ;
    }   // if ( dwError )

    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  If we want to support event categories, we have also to register the
    //  CategoryMessageFile, and set CategoryCount. Note that categories need to
    //  have the message ids 1 to CategoryCount!
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if ( dwCategoryCount > 0x00000000 )
    {
        if ( !(pszCategories && pszMessages) )
        {
            if ( !(( HMODULE ) GetModuleFileNameA ( m_hinstDLL , szPath , 260 )) )
            {
                return util::ReportErrorOnConsole ( ) ;
            }   // Unless ( ( HMODULE ) GetModuleFileName ( m_hinstDLL , szPath , MAX_PATH ) )
        }   // Unless ( pszCategories && pszMessages )

        dwError         = RegSetValueExA ( hRegKey ,                                        // Handle to key
                                           "CategoryMessageFile" ,                          // Value name
                                           0x00000000L ,                                    // Reserved - pass NULL
                                           ( 2 ) ,                                          // Value type
                                           MsgFileNameString ( pszMessages ,
                                                               pszCategories ,
                                                               lpszPath ) ,                 // Value data
                                           MsgFileNameLen    ( pszMessages ,
                                                               pszCategories ,
                                                               lpszPath ) ) ;               // Size of value data

        if ( dwError )
        {
            return util::ReportErrorOnConsole ( dwError ) ;
        }   // if ( dwError )

        dwError         = RegSetValueExA ( hRegKey ,                                        // handle to key
                                           "CategoryCount" ,                                // value name
                                           0x00000000L ,                                    // reserved
                                           ( 4 ) ,                                          // value type
                                           ( PBYTE ) &dwCategoryCount ,                     // value data
                                           sizeof dwCategoryCount ) ;                       // size of value data
        if ( dwError )
        {
            return util::ReportErrorOnConsole ( dwError ) ;
        }   // if ( dwError )
    }   // if ( dwCategoryCount > 0 )

    dwError                 = RegCloseKey ( hRegKey ) ;

    if ( dwError )
    {
        return util::ReportErrorOnConsole ( dwError ) ;
    }   // if ( dwError )
    else
    {
        return util::AnnounceChangeToAll ( ) ;
    }   // FALSE (UNexpected outcome) block, if ( lr )
}   // DWORD •
```

The DLL project has a module definition file. Excluding the internal documentation, it is as follows.

```
LIBRARY   EventLoggingForAll

VERSION 1, 0, 0, 1

EXPORTS
    AddEventSource         @2
    RemoveEventSource      @3
```

With respect to the DLL, `dumpbin.exe` gives the following reports on the DLL file and its import library.

```
Microsoft (R) COFF Binary File Dumper Version 6.00.8447
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Documents and Settings\DAG\My Documents\Programming\Visual Studio 6\DLL\EventLogging\Debug\EventLoggingForAll.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

             2    _AddEventSource@20
             3    _RemoveEventSource@8

  Summary

          A8 .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           4 .idata$4
           4 .idata$5
          18 .idata$6
Microsoft (R) COFF Binary File Dumper Version 6.00.8447
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Documents and Settings\DAG\My Documents\Programming\Visual Studio 6\DLL\EventLogging\Debug\EventLoggingForAll.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for EventLoggingForAll.dll

           0 characteristics
    54BB1CE9 time date stamp Sat Jan 17 20:39:37 2015
        0.00 version
           2 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          2    0 00001014 AddEventSource
          3    1 00001019 RemoveEventSource

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       12000 .text
```

Everything appears to be in order, yet the link step reports `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__AddEventSource` when I try to build the console program.

One final note; the error doesn't appear to be the result of the linker not seeing the import library, because it is the first library searched, and I can see it listed as such in the build log. I am also certain that there isn't an old version of the import library that could interfere, because I deleted every instance of it from the machine, verified that they were all gone, and started fresh.

Comment: Pick either dllexport or a module definition file. Don't do both.

Comment: Mr. Chen, initially, I had only `dllexport`, and I was getting nowhere. Besides, every other project in my collection has both, and I've never read or heard anything to discourage using both. The only thing I can see that is different about this project is that everything in this project, on both sides of the boundary, is c++; hence, the extern "C" in the prototypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__AddEventSource

The linker error message says what you are doing wrong.  It is looking for _AddEventSource but that's *not* the name of your exported function.  It is _AddEventSource@20.  Note the added "@20" name decoration.  You obfuscated the problem by using a DEF file, but it is still visible from the dump of the .lib file.

This linker error is very much by design, it protects the client of your DLL from a exceedingly nasty problem.  Your question contains no hints, but if the info is accurate, you changed a global compile option.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Advanced, "Calling Convention" setting.  The default is /Gd, you changed it to /Gz.  But did *not* make the same change in the client project.  This is so nasty because any call that the client code makes to an exported function will unbalance the stack.  The runtime errors that this can cause are very hard to diagnose.  The @20 postfix was designed to not let it come this far.

Change the setting back and make the calling convention explicit by adding the `__stdcall` attribute to the function declaration.

Other mistakes you are making:

- Very important, not just for this problem, is to have only *one* .h file that declares the exported functions.  Suitable to be #included into the client program's source code.  That way there will never be a mismatch between the DLL and the client.  This includes the need to put __stdcall in the declaration, now the DLL and client will always agree and a mismatch in the /G option can't hurt anybody.
- The way you are using the TCHAR types (like PCTSTR in your declaration) is very, very nasty as well.  You now critically depend on another global compile option.  Project + Properties, General, "Character Set".  You changed this one as well from the default so it is very, very easy to overlook that in the client project.  This mistake is way nastier than the /Gz option since you do *not* get a linker error for that one when you use extern "C".  The misbehavior you get a runtime is a bit easier to diagnose, you'll only lose an hour or two of your life when you discover that the strings only contain a single character.  Stop using TCHAR completely, it stopped being relevant 10 years ago.  Your code as written can only work with `char*`.
- The VERSION statement in the DEF file is wrong, it can have only 2 digits that must be separated by a `.`.  That produces a link error on later VS versions.  You should omit it completely, it has been outdated for over 20 years, the version number should be set in a VERSION resource.  Don't skip adding the resource to your .rc file, very easy to do in VS, versioning is import for DLLs.

Comment: Your proposed solution worked correctly; reverting the default calling convention of the DLL project to __cdecl allowed the console program to link, and I could see the difference in the dumpbin report on the import library; the decoration was gone.

Comment: BTW, I neglected to mention that I knew that the name decoration was the source of the problem, but I was unable to discover how to fix it. It didn't occur to me that the experimental change in the default calling convention was the source of the problem; after all, the exported routines had explicit calling conventions.

Comment: With respect to the TCHAR type, I am not finished. The sample from which this code is derived cast the arguments to PCTSTR. The final version will have them cast to LPCTSTR, and will have both ANSI and Unicode implementations.  I have been using TCHARs in conjunction with the generic TCHAR mappings defined in `TCHAR.H` since 2005, I am keenly aware of many of the pitfalls, and I think I have taken adequate steps to mitigate them.

Comment: With respect to the VERSION statement in the DEF file, I say "good riddance;" it's one fewer things to keep in sync. I began adding it several years ago, when I noticed it in the documentation of the module definition file, assuming that it must cover some case not covered by the VERSION resource. I have been using them, too, since the beginning.

Comment: With respect to headers, I have one only, although it was not obvious from the material that I posted. All of my DLL header files have the same base name as the DLL. The comment at the top of the function declaration is taken from the header for this one. The output shown is the result of my effort to verify that the declaration was being generated correctly, as __declspec(dllimport), in the calling routine, and as __declspec(dllexport) in the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you are building your project as 64-bit or 32-bit and that the library is found in the correct bin folder under x64 or x86.

From personal experience, I was trying to add an a new exported function to a dll I was maintaining and could not get the compiler to link against the new exported function. It turned out I had inadvertently changed the  build target to x86 while trying to update the 64-bit version of the dll.

Comment: Build target isn't an issue; everything is 32 bits.

Comment: Notwithstanding what I said about build target not being an issue in _this_ case, the suggestion is a worthy one to keep in mind.